# Is my SD card failing on my Banana Pi?

Tags: performance, sd-card

My BananaPi has become very slow over the last few weeks. Often `top` reports load average: `1.02, 1.06, 1.14` or much much higher numbers. And stats for idle CPU and I/O wait times are really high `40 id,  10 wa`.

I've checked a few other things such as `iotop` and `free -m` but haven't found one particular process that is causing the brunt of the problems.

At a guess I think the SD card might be failing.

How can I verify if this is the case. Or should I just buy a new SD card and backup my current one ASAP?

Comment: If it were failing, I'd expect programs to be forced to wait longer for disk access, if anything. What do you mean by "slow" anyway, just higher load averages? I don't see how they're related directly to the sd card. At any rate, sd cards are relatively cheap, just copy everything (`dd` on another system) onto a new one and give it a try.

Comment: Often the top usage nunbers have been 4+ for overall CPU stats in 1, 5 & 15 mins.  And when accessing ftp, SSH and samba shares they'll often timeout because the system is under too much stress for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program that is called RMPrep this is normally used to wipe the SD or USB but they have a test program called TEST SPEED and QUICK SIZE TEST. This may come up with error if its failing

Please note that im not sure if they will auto format the SD so please give there webside a read first.

https://www.rmprepusb.com/